# Comma separated list in a datalayer variable

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a datalayer variable for a category on a page. I've got this firing correctly however the values within this variable can be multiple categories and therefore presented as a comma separated list:

```
dataLayer = [{
'storeCategory': 'major store', 'food', 'childrenswear', 'health & beauty'
 }];
```

What I would like to do is fire a GA event for each and every catgeory in the list:

```
Event catgeory: "Store"
Event action: "ViewCategory"
Event label: {storeCategory value}
```

I have a feeling I need to use a custom JavaScript variable to parse the list but not sure how this links in with triggers or tags.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your dataLayer is incorrect, the 'storeCategory' variable should be an array, I think you're just missing the brackets.

I'm not sure how much help you need, but essentially you need to:

1. Create a datalayer variable to capture the storeCategory array.
2. Create a custom html tag that fires on "all pages" to loop through the storeCategory array, like so:

.

```
<script>
  var cats = {{store category}};
  var catLen = cats.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < catLen; i++){
   dataLayer.push({
     'event': 'category-view',
     'category':cats[i]
   });

  }
</script>
```

3. Create another datalayer variable to capture the "category" variable from step 2.
4. Create a custom event trigger to trigger on "category-view" or whatever you name it.
5. Create a GA event tag and capture the "category" variable in the "label", make sure you set it to non-interaction.

Comment: You shouldn't ever be pushing to the dataLayer from within GTM itself. It's bad practice as it can be confusing when events can come from both outside and inside GTM. Use the built-in Tag Sequencing capabilities if you're trying to implement dependencies between tags.